# Hydrolysis of Sucrose over Sn1Ac or Sn2Ac

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, stereoelectronics

In *"March's Advanced Organic Chemistry"* I have read about the general mechanism of the acetal hydrolysis. It names the acid-catalyzed S<sub>N</sub>1 or S<sub>N</sub>2 as a possible mechanism for a Acetal-hydrolysis.

Now I am interested to know if S<sub>N</sub>1 or S<sub>N</sub>2 is mainly going on at the **Hydrolysis of Sucrose** to Glucose and Fructose. So I compared the different parameters which influence S<sub>N</sub>1/S<sub>N</sub>2.

- **Polarity of the solvent:** Water -> really polar -> S<sub>N</sub>1 preferred.
- **Stabilization of a possible Carbokation-Intermediat:** Primary (Anomeric C!), so not really stabilized by Hyperconjunction -> S<sub>N</sub>2 preferred. (*Is there Hyperconjunction also in the ether-O?*)
- **Mesomeric stabilization** There is also a mesomeric stabilization between the resulting carbocation and a Oxonium-Ion in the S<sub>N</sub>1-Mechanism.
- **Steric Hindrance:** In my opinion, through the planar region around the anomeric C (planar ether), there is no steric hindrance -> S<sub>N</sub>2 possible.
- **Temperature:** high temperature -> S<sub>N</sub>1 preferred.

So to conclude: Many different aspects. Because of the main points "steric hindrance" and the destabilized primary carbocation intermediate I would conclude that the hydrolysis of Sucrose goes mainly (maybe a little bit over S<sub>N</sub>1) over S<sub>N</sub>2.

Have I forgotten something important? Are my assumptions "No steric hindrance" and primary carbocation-intermediate correct?

I have attached my possible S<sub>N</sub>1-mechanism.

[image]

Comment: Unstabilized primary cations **never** undergo $S_N1$ reactions so yes you are correct.

Comment: @bon So the mesomeric stabilization isn't enough stabilization?

Comment: I would not call the intermediate a primary carbocation. Yes the primary carbocation is one of the resonance forms but it is an extremely minor one. The oxonium ion resonance form is a much larger contributor. In any case, both pathways are possible. The SN1 mechanism you have drawn is perfectly correct. In addition to the factors you considered, the SN1 pathway is particularly favoured for the β-anomer because of the anomeric effect (n -> σ* donation from ring oxygen lone pair into C-O σ*).

Comment: @orthocresol Tanks for your answer! So the oxonium-resonance-structure stabilize the whole S<sub>N</sub>1 intermediat and so we can assume that also the S<sub>N</sub>1-mechanism happens also at a "big" amount?

Comment: @orthocresol To the anomeric effekt: Sucrose has the Alpha-D-Glucose-monosaccharid, so the the anomeric OH-group makes the whole intermediat not more stable. But if the Glucose-rest is the leaving group, and Fructose works as the intermediat (is that the case?), there your spoken Anomeric effect works?

Comment: Yes the SN1 pathway does occur significantly in carbohydrate reactions. Also, oops... sorry. The anomeric effect works for the anomer which has the leaving group placed in an axial position, which in this case is the α-anomer. My bad.

Comment: @user2365846 Primary cations that are otherwise unstabilised do not undergo SN1. However, this one is highly stabilised by the neighbouring oxygen so it will. Sorry I wrote my previous comment without properly looking at the structure.

Answer (score 4):

The mechanism supplied in the question statement is wrong according to [this paper](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja00227a017?journalCode=jacsat), where the evidence favored Carbon-Oxygen bond cleavage on the fructosyl-side instead of the glucosyl-side of the bridge Oxygen. As that reference states, "the initial products of the hydrolysis are a-D-glucose and a fructosyl carboxonium ion"

[image]

But don't feel bad, many textbooks have shown the same mechanism (detailed in the Discussion section of the paper). It's possible that the reaction mechanism changes with conditions, but I know of no evidence for that.

However, the same paper discusses that the mechanism was thought to depend on the type of sugar undergoing bond cleavage:

[image]

Results from a [computational study](https://doi.org/10.1021/jo3027565) show that SN1 mechanisms via a carbocation on fructose and glucose are both feasible, with the one on fructose slightly more likely.

Some other points:

1) The question statement refers to "primary" carbocations twice, and so do three of the comments. But in this reaction the 2 alternatives are a secondary or tertiary carboxoniun ion (for this terminology see [Olah (1998) Onium Ions](https://books.google.com/books?id=KCGmTwwc3AcC&pg=PA270&lpg=PA270&dq=secondary%20carboxonium%20ion&source=bl&ots=isiQE2chG0&sig=lfAKgn0QZuoa5nb6HkSnnLRTkC0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiN7ML5g67ZAhXHMGMKHdd2D_YQ6AEIMDAB#v=onepage&q=secondary%20carboxonium%20ion&f=false) or ref 11 of the above paper).

2) It makes sense that an SN1-type mechanism would take place on the fructosyl-side of the bridge Oxygen since the resulting carboxoniun is tertiary rather than secondary.

Now, the real question is: How would you experimentally determine the mechanism? That is where the science comes in. The fact that so many textbook authors have presented this classic reaction with different mechanisms should be a big lesson to all students.  That expert authors would go to the extent of drawing detailed reaction mechanisms in a textbook that are not backed up by experimental reality, shows how mistrustful we should be of any non-experiment-based opinions. And this is for a classic, textbook example.  How much more unreliable "expert opinions" are for much more complicated things!